# jQuery CrossDomain iframe Mousemove function

Tags: jquery, iframe, vimeo, mousemove

I'm working on project where I'm embedding vimeo videos FULLSCREEN using code :

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/...../.." width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I'm using Mousemove function on parent page to show company logo on Mousemove like this :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $top = $('#logo');
    var $document = $(document);
    var timer = null;
    var timerIsRunning = false;

    $top.hide();

    $document.mousemove(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
                    $document.mousemove(function(e) {
                            if($top.is(':hidden')) {
                                $top.fadeIn(2000);
                            } else {
                                if(!timerIsRunning) {
                                    timerIsRunning = true;
                                    clearTimeout(timer);
                                    timer = setTimeout(function() { $top.fadeOut();  }, 15000);
                                    setTimeout(function() {timerIsRunning = true;}, 15000);
                                }
                            }
                    });
            }, 2000);

});
```

My issue is browser doesn't detect Mousemove function over embedded fullscreen video & that is why Logo div doesn't appear...

Using CSS `pointer-events: none;` It works but disabled Video Player Control.

Is there any Solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the mousemove event in the iframe :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $top = $('#logo');
    var $document = $(document);
    var timer = null;
    var timerIsRunning = false;

    $top.hide();

    $document.mousemove(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#iframe',$document).mousemove(function(e) {
                            if($top.is(':hidden')) {
                                $top.fadeIn(2000);
                            } else {
                                if(!timerIsRunning) {
                                    timerIsRunning = true;
                                    clearTimeout(timer);
                                    timer = setTimeout(function() { $top.fadeOut();  }, 15000);
                                    setTimeout(function() {timerIsRunning = true;}, 15000);
                                }
                            }
                    });
            }, 2000);

    });
```